# Does Java regex unicode support include full case folding?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, case-folding

Assuming these string definitions:

```java
String lowerStream = "ﬂüßchen";
String upperStream = "FLÜSSCHEN";
String streamPattern = ".*(ss).*";
```

Using this pattern:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(streamPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

...this assertion passes:

```java
assertThat( pattern.matcher(upperStream).find() ).isTrue()
```

...and this one fails:

```java
assertThat( pattern.matcher(lowerStream).find() ).isTrue()
```

...whereas *both* `lowerStream` and `upperStream` pass on [rubular.com](https://rubular.com/) with each of these regexes:

`/.*(ss).*/i`

`/.*(SS).*/i`

`/.*(ß).*/i`

It is also not possible to get a successful comparison using any of `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`, `String.toLowerCase().equals()`, or `String.toUpperCase().equals()`.

Does java's unicode regex only support simple case folding? If so, why is this not explicitly documented?

Comment: "If so, why is this not explicitly documented?" - Are you asking why Oracle's javadocs in particular don't mention it?

Comment: Have you checked `Character.toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`?  Just curious, I don't know if it's different.

Comment: I want to be sure I'm not misunderstanding what to expect from the `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE` flag. And, if one of those things is that it does NOT support full case folding, I'd like to know if it is documented *anywhere* that this is the case, since I didn't find any caveats in the javadoc writeups for that flag

Comment: @markspace: I haven't, but will check

Answer (score 1):

On my system, it seems to convert lower case correctly to upper:

```
public class IfTesting {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String lowerStream = "ﬂüßchen";
      String upperStream = "FLÜSSCHEN";
      System.out.println( "upper case: " + Arrays.toString( upperStream.getBytes()) );
      System.out.println( "lower case to upper: " + Arrays.toString( lowerStream.toUpperCase().getBytes() ) );
   }

}
```

Results in output:

```
run:
upper case: [70, 76, -61, -100, 83, 83, 67, 72, 69, 78]
lower case to upper: [70, 76, 85, -52, -120, 83, 83, 67, 72, 69, 78]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

And you can see that 'S' (83 decimal) appears in the output.  I don't know if this helps, but it appears at some level that Java understands how to convert the characters you provided.  OTOH I'm guessing that since 83 is clearly in the ASCII range, it will be converted to a lower case ASCII 's' if you attempt to go the other way.  So that might make it better to convert to upper case.  You're using lower case 'ss' in your match string.

Comment: Changing the pattern to use `SS` fails to find or match on ﬂüßchen

Comment: This could be a bug in the regex.  Maybe consider asking on the Open JDK discussion list?